# Treating null as a value in a polars anti-join

Tags: python-polars

I'm using polars` anti join to convert updates to a dataset into "deltas".

This works great when all of my column values are populated:

```py
import polars as pl

my_dataset = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": ["x", "y", "z"],
        "c": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    }
).lazy()

my_update = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "b": ["x", "y", "z", "q"],
        "c": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
    }
).lazy()

my_delta = my_update.join(my_dataset, on=my_update.columns, how="anti")
```

However, when one or more of the columns contain `Null`, the default behaviour is to not report a match. For example:

```py
my_dataset = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 5],
        "b": ["x", "y", "z", pl.Null],
        "c": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
    }
).lazy()

my_update = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "b": ["x", "y", "z", "q", pl.Null],
        "c": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
    }
).lazy()

my_delta = my_update.join(my_dataset, on=my_update.columns, how="anti")
```

Produces:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | q | 0.4 |
| 5 | Null | 0.5 |

While [I understand why this is the case](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9738), I am looking for a way to get:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | q | 0.4 |

i.e. to consider the row containing a `Null` in both tables as a match.

#### What are my options for going about doing this?

Some potential caveats:

- The real data I'm dealing with has > 50 columns of variable data types.
- The null values can occur in (almost) any column.
- I would prefer not to have to fill the `Null`s (or, if this is the only option, to be able to recover the original `Null`s somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was to add `join_nulls=True`:

```py
my_delta = my_update.join(my_dataset, on=my_update.columns, how="anti", join_nulls=True)
```